# How to Change Button Color IntegerUpDown (Extended WPF Toolkit)?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=NumericUpDown

I'm trying to change the Arrow Button Background Color to Blue.

I believe it has something to do with SpinnerButtonStyleKey:

https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes.ResourceKeys~SpinnerButtonStyleKey.html#

I was able to change the TextBox Background and Foreground using a png image in the Setter.

[image]

I found how to change the Arrow Color using:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static theme:ResourceKeys.GlyphNormalForegroundKey}" Color="White"/>
```

Here is the XAML template:

```
<Style x:Key="IntegerUpDownBlue" TargetType="{x:Type wpfTool:IntegerUpDown}">        
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Images/TextBoxEnabled.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Bottom"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlNormalBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes1:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
<Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Focusable="False" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wpfTool:IntegerUpDown}">
            <wpfTool:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner" AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ButtonSpinnerLocation="{Binding ButtonSpinnerLocation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <wpfTool:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" AutoMoveFocus="{Binding AutoMoveFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AutoSelectBehavior="{Binding AutoSelectBehavior, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" IsUndoEnabled="True" MinWidth="20" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SelectAllOnGotFocus="{Binding SelectAllOnGotFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextAlignment="{Binding TextAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" WatermarkTemplate="{Binding WatermarkTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Watermark="{Binding Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </wpfTool:ButtonSpinner>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlMouseOverBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes1:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding AllowTextInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlSelectedBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes1:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Images/TextBoxDisabled.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Bottom"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADD5FF"/>
                    <!-- <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/> -->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I tried changing this part, adding a SolidColorBrush x:Key, but I see no change.

```
<wpfTool:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner"...
 Background="{StaticResource IntegerUpDown.volume.Spinner.Static.Background}"
```

I tried chaning BorderBrush:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
```

I also tried this solution but the code is messed up and says "Error The closing XML tag "RepeatButton" is mismatched:

[wpf toolkit datetimepicker how to change color of spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153667/wpf-toolkit-datetimepicker-how-to-change-color-of-spinner)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a **IntegerUpDown**, I created a similar **ButtonSpinner** to look through the template code. Since the Arrow Color used ***GlyphNormalForegroundKey*** I looked for what the Background was using, it was ***SpinnerButtonStyleKey*** in the **RepeatButton**. It worked on the IntegerUpDown.

I put together this code, place it anywhere to override the buttons.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static theme:ResourceKeys.SpinnerButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```