# Repeat Button Style Setter/Triggers Doesn't Work

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using the Extended WPF Toolkit's IntegerUpDown control.

[I was able to stylize the arrow buttons in a previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404706/how-to-change-button-color-integerupdown-extended-wpf-toolkit)

[image: Before Style] Before

[image: After Style] After

**I've run into some additional style problems:**

I'm using PresentationFramework.Aero and Aero2.

```
<!-- RepeatButton Style -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Static theme:ResourceKeys.SpinnerButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="RepeatButton">                 
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />               
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Link to the full XAML: http://pastebin.com/ETYgHEpz

The IsEnabled False Trigger will not override the Disabled Background or Border Color. It always stays White, I need it Transparent. However I can override the Opacity and BorderThickness. (Windows 10):

[image: Disabled Background Win10]

Cannot change the IsMouseOver Background Color, always Light Blue. (Windows 10):

[image: MouseOver Color]

Windows 7 always displays a White Border, even if BorderThickeness is 0 and Color is Transparent or {x:Null}:

[image: Win7 Border]

I think it is being overriden by a Control Template, but IntergerUpDown doesn't have a RepeatButton Style within the Control Template and I've had trouble trying to add one. I had to create the Style outside.

Answer (score 1):

some properties won't work when you set via Style setters. This is because of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx). Try changing the values in ControlTemplate triggers.

Comment: The IntegerUpDown is missing a Control Template Trigger for RepeatButton. When I try to add one it gives a error warning. I had to style it globally outside of the Control Template. For now I've had to remove the Extended Toolkit and create an UpDown control myself using TextBox, Buttons, C#, and styled it through xaml.